A short film where businessmen are wearing tape players?
Haven't had any luck finding this through Google or other communities. I watched a short on IFC probably in the mid-to-late 90s.
There was a conference room full of men, but they had very exaggerated faces, possibly blockheads. Instead of speaking they had tape players/recorders around their necks. The boss tells a joke (I think) and they all play their tapes which have recorded laughter on them, but the main guy can't turn his recorder off, and it keeps playing laughter. He looks horrified, with a big gaping mouth. The boss summons him and gives him a different tape, and he knows what it is, but he has no choice. He puts it into his recorder and it plays a scream as he jumps out the window.
It may or may not be black & white.

Yes, exactly! At least someone else recognizes it!

It's Louis C.K's "Hello There"!



http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2275400/combined
There was more than the office scene, leading up to it.
The character played by Ron Lynch carries a tape recorder around his neck and only converses by apparently pre-recorded messages. At first everybody he encounters reacts "as expected", apparently puzzled by the strange concept.
But then he enters the building where the business meeting is held, where everybody is wearing a tape recorder around their neck.
The scene proceeds as described in the question.
